# package keyval error undefined color beamer

Tags: beamer, color

When i compile the following code, i get the package keyval error, undefined code. Please help!

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newcent}
\usepackage{color}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\setbeamercolor{normal text}{teal}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[vertical shading][top=white,bottom=blue]
Texte n'ayant pas encore subi de changement de couleur.

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

you have to use *beamer colors*, that is a foreground and background color:

```
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=teal}
```

Comment: for a backgroundcolor use `bg=...`